# Cannot install Gradle in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

Hi need help on adding gradle in eclipes. I tried to install new software in eclipes update site but i kept on having this error

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Spring UAA Integration (optional) 3.6.2.201410090827-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa.feature.feature.group 3.6.2.201410090827-RELEASE)
  Missing requirement: Spring UAA Integration 3.6.2.201410090827-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa 3.6.2.201410090827-RELEASE) requires 'package com.google.protobuf 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring UAA Integration (optional) 3.6.2.201410090827-RELEASE (org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa.feature.feature.group 3.6.2.201410090827-RELEASE)
    To: org.springframework.ide.eclipse.uaa [3.6.2.201410090827-RELEASE]
```

I've already tried to add additional update sites to satisfy some dependencies. by exporting this (http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/composite/e3.7/bookmarks.xml) but still kept on getting the same error.please help me with this.

Comment: Did you install Spring UAA Integration?

Comment: yes i already have, but it's working now bad new's is the older version of eclipse is not compatible for ECLIPSE JUNO, that's what I think because for ECLIPSE LUNA 4.4 it's working smoothly...sad news now is I need to update eclipse and add ADT & SDK all over again LOL hahahaha...thanks anyway